# Is there a good CAS client I could use without a web platform?

Tags: c#, mono, cas, jasig

I need to authenticate against an existing CAS server from within a Mono desktop client application. The closest thing I've found is [Jasig](https://github.com/Jasig) which would work great if I were using an ASP.NET application.

Does anyone know of a good library out there, or a way I could adapt Jasig to work from an executable?

Answer (score 1):

The CAS servers supports RESTful APIs. You could use the API to submit ticket/validation requests.
See here for more info, plz: https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CASUM/RESTful+API